# Add filtrable attribute column in products in category grid

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, product-grid

I'm using Magento 2.3 and I'm trying to add a column with an attribute inside the "products in category" grid (Catalog->Categories->Products in Category).
I've created a custom module and the file `Product.php` in

> Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Catalog\Adminhtml\Category\Tab

I'm pasting the code below:

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\Mymodule\Block\Catalog\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{


/**
 * @return Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $grid = parent::_prepareCollection();

    $collection = $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    if ($this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
        $this->getCollection()->clear();
    }

    return $grid;
}

/**
 * @return Extended
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->addColumn(
        'manufacturer',
        [
            'header' => __('Manufacturer'),
            'name' => 'manufacturer',
            'index' => 'manufacturer',
        ]
    );


    return $this;
}
}
```

I'm attaching the screenshot of the result:
[image]

As you can see the column gets added and the attribute displayed, but with the id of the option instead of the text label.
How can I change my code so that it returns the attribute label (in this case woul be "test") instead of the value?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Davide , have you got the solution for above , if so can you share complete snippet

Answer (score 1):

**Add Column Like This :-**

```
$this->addColumn(
        'manufacturer',
        [
            'header' => __('Manufacturer'),
            'name' => 'manufacturer',
            'index' => 'manufacturer',
            'type'      =>'options',
            'options'   => $this->getManufacturer()
        ]
    );
```

**And Create `getManufacturer()` Function for get Manufacturer Name :-**

```
public function getManufacturer()
    {
        $manuf = $this->yourFactory->create();
        $test = array();
        foreach ($test->getData() as $testData) {
            $test[$testData['manufacturer_name']] = $testData['manufacturer_name'];
        }
        return $test;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing your answer but I don't have any factory set up. Do i need to use object manager for that?

Comment: in file create public function __construct(){ } and call your factory

Comment: @RkRathod , Hi i have added filed to grid but unable to save and retrieve the data in the field. Can you explain how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ronak Rathod's answer is correct. Let me improve it, so that it will be helpful for others too

in module `di.xml` add this entry

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>
```

Now use this code in your overrided file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    protected $attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository,
        array $data = [],
        Visibility $visibility = null,
        Status $status = null
    )
    {
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $productFactory, $coreRegistry, $data, $visibility, $status);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $grid = parent::_prepareCollection();

        $collection = $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        if ($this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->clear();
        }

        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        try {
            $this->addColumn(
                'manufacturer',
                [
                    'header' => __('Manufacturer'),
                    'name' => 'manufacturer',
                    'index' => 'manufacturer',
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options'   => $this->getBrandsOptionArray()
                ]
            );
        }
        catch (\Exception $e){
            //Do nothing
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBrandsOptionArray()
    {
        $options = $this->attributeRepository->get("mgs_brand")->getOptions();
        $optionsArray = [];
        foreach ($options as $option){
            if($option->getValue() == 0){
                continue;
            }
            $optionsArray[$option->getValue()] = $option->getLabel();
        }

        asort($optionsArray);
        return ($optionsArray);
    }
}
```

I have changed the function `getBrandsOptionArray` to get manufacturer options