# Add editable attribute column in products in category grid

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, grid, category-products, product-edit

I have added an extra editable attribute column in "Products in category" grid. I am using the below link to add the column.

[Add filtrable attribute column in products in category grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279053/add-filtrable-attribute-column-in-products-in-category-grid)

Here is my structure

[image]
Now I want to save the value on category save. How can I do that?

Comment: did you solved this?